# Dynamically Show/Hide input box based on Service Response

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have a scenario , where If I click on a radio button 5 input text boxes are present initially.But the moment I click on the radio button a service request will be sent and based on the response, I need to hide some of the unwanted text boxes.

**Ex :**

```
<input id="1" [(ngModel)]="name"></input>
<input id="2" [(ngModel)]="dob"></input>
<input id="3" [(ngModel)]="city"></input>
<input id="4" [(ngModel)]="state"></input>
<input id="5" [(ngModel)]="country"></input>
```

**Service Response :**

```
{
"id": 1,
"value": "First",
},
{
"id": 2,
"value": "Second",
}
```

So now I need to hide all input elements except id = 1 and 2.

I have tried this approach, and it works as well

```
<div *ngFor="let res of response">
<input id="1" *ngIf="res.id===1" [(ngModel)]="name"></input>
<input id="2" *ngIf="res.id===2" [(ngModel)]="dob"></input>
<input id="3" *ngIf="res.id===3" [(ngModel)]="city"></input>
<input id="4" *ngIf="res.id===4" [(ngModel)]="state"></input>
<input id="5" *ngIf="res.id===5" [(ngModel)]="country"></input>
</div>
```

But this approach seems not ideal since unnecessary looping takes place.

Is there a better way to achieve my need ?

P.S : **id** attribute is just a placeholder here

Comment: There is no need for the `*ngFor` just use `response` like this in every input: `*ngIf="response.id===1"`. Adjust the condition in order to meet the initial show/hide criteria.

Comment: Unless you want to display those text boxes on init, just loop through the response and display like `<input id={{res.id}}></input>`..

Comment: Its an array mate

Comment: the 'id' attribute is just a placeholder here, I added it for better understanding

Comment: In the .ts file use `let res : any;` in the `res = response from server` In template use `*ngIf = res.id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly achieve it by looping the `input`. Every time when the `response` variable gets new values, it will automatically update the `dom`

```
<input *ngFor="let res of response" id="{{res.id}}"></input>
```

Okay As you have edited your code and now it seems, only element iteration won't work. Your current approach is not bad for this but I can suggest another approach.

```
<input *ngFor="let res of response" id="{{res.id}}" [(ngModel)]="binding[res.id]"></input>
```

and in your bindings, you can have an array of like

```
let binding = [1:"name",2:"dob",3:"city",4:"state",5:"country"]
```

Comment: mate forget about that id attribute in element

Comment: What do you want exactly, just to optimize your approach or else?

Comment: Optimize my approach to see if this can be achieved without iteration

Comment: `ngFor` interactions are optimized enough by angular itself, we need not to worry about.